# getting case insensitive completions with compgen in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm trying to get my command (devmode2) auto-completing with bash working with *compgen -W*, my bashrc has:

```
_devmode2() {
    COMPREPLY=()
    local sonames=$(devmode2 --auto --current "${COMP_CWORD}" -- ${COMP_WORDS[@]})
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${sonames}" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}))
}
complete -F _devmode2 devmode2
```

An example auto-completion

```
$ devmode2 g<tab>
```

results in *sonames* having the following values:

```
game-life-adv
game-life-sparse
getopt-alt
git-workflow
git-workflow-extra
github-testers
group-git
group-git-ivan
Group-Git-Taggers-Maven
Group-Git-Taggers-Node
Group-Git-Taggers-Perl
Group-Git-Taggers-Ruby
```

but my auto-completion results in the following suggestions:

```
game-life-adv       game-life-sparse    getopt-alt          github-testers      git-workflow        git-workflow-extra  group-git           group-git-ivan
```

How can I get all the values I pass to *compgen* back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `compgen` does not have an option to do case-insensitive filtering of the list of options you give it.

There is a `readline` variable which you can set to cause filename completion to be case-insensitive:

```
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
```

but that doesn't affect the behaviour of `compgen`, so it probably won't apply to programmable completion. (Its behaviour is a bit odd with filenames, too.)

That leaves you with the possibility of doing your own filtering instead of using `compgen` (or in conjunction with `compgen` if you require features other than filtering, which is not the case in your example).

You could do that with a simple iteration over the list of alternatives, doing a case-insensitive prefix comparison, but the following little function should work:

```
_devmode2() {
  local sonames=($(devmode2 --auto --current "${COMP_CWORD}" -- ${COMP_WORDS[@]}))
  local prefix="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  COMPREPLY=($(printf %s\\n "${sonames[@]}" |
               awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v p="$prefix" \
                   'p==substr($0,0,length(p))'))
}
```

If `devmode2` outputs one alternative per line, it would be easier to just use it as the input to `awk`. Also, the second argument of the completion function is, as far as I know, always the same as `${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}`. So this might be simpler:

```
_devmode2() {
  COMPREPLY=($(devmode2 -auto --current "${COMP_CWORD}" -- "${COMP_WORDS[@]}" \
               awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -v p="$2" \
                   'p==substr($0,0,length(p))'))
}
```

Comment: That worked although I didn't need to awk part.